# Do Cygwin paths propagate to native Python?

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I'm invoking a native (Windows) Python installation from Cygwin, and I'm
surprised to find that appending Cygwin paths, *excluding those
starting with ~*, to sys.path appear to be picked up successfully
by Python.
I can't wrap my head around why that is. I'd assume as much for
Python within Cygwin, but for native Python I'd think proper
Windows paths would have to be provided.

Why does this work? What am I not getting and where  can I find out more?

**/home/waldo/foo/bar.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/waldo/foo/baz')
print 'sys.path:\n%s' % sys.path

import qux
qux.say_hi()
```

**/home/waldo/foo/baz/qux.py**

```
def say_hi():
    print 'hi'
```

> ```
> $ cd /home/waldo/foo
> $ /cygdrive/c/Python_2_7_13/python.exe bar.py
> sys.path:
> ['C:\\home\\waldo\\foo', ..., '/home/waldo/foo/baz']
> hi
> ```

Comment: "/home/waldo/foo/baz" is relative to the drive or UNC share of the process working directory. That's a function of Windows -- not Python.

Comment: @eryksun I wasn't aware; you should post an answer!